# Spring Security - localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

when I run my application on tomcat, the page returns this error: localhost redirected you too many times

The login page must be custom.

Here is my controller class and method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login.htm")
public class LoginFormController {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Returning login view");

        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        return new ModelAndView("login", "model", myModel);
    }
    
}
```

this is my securityFilterChain method

```
    @Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->  authorize
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true).permitAll());
    
  return http.build();
}
```

in console I have this trace and debug information:

```
2024-03-11T13:19:57.812+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/demo/error?continue to session
2024-03-11T13:19:57.812+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/demo/login
2024-03-11T13:19:57.817+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.817+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7ff90f3e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@73a93162, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@ec11749, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@ad824f9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@42d7ffe5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@70fba437, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5ca6435b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@10be5d15, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2273e500, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@106eac2a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5353b529, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6cbfa329]] (1/1)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.817+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6768e172]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@6768e172] using org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer$$Lambda$540/0x000000080053a860@5d9c15c9
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-03-11T13:19:57.818+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/demo/login", parameters={}
2024-03-11T13:19:57.819+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 5941141B4FD07EED2E16EF1676DC2D46 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.820+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5941141B4FD07EED2E16EF1676DC2D46], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7ff90f3e, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@73a93162, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@ec11749, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@ad824f9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@42d7ffe5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@70fba437, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5ca6435b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@10be5d15, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2273e500, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@106eac2a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5353b529, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@6cbfa329]] (1/1)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 DEBUG 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (7/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/login', POST]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (8/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : matchingRequestParameterName is required for getMatchingRequest to lookup a value, but not provided
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (9/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (10/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2024-03-11T13:19:57.821+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@51924b66]]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.822+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@51924b66]] using org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager@324e7f3
2024-03-11T13:19:57.822+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not find SecurityContext in HttpSession 5941141B4FD07EED2E16EF1676DC2D46 using the SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT session attribute
2024-03-11T13:19:57.822+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.822+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.822+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5941141B4FD07EED2E16EF1676DC2D46], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2024-03-11T13:19:57.823+01:00 TRACE 11604 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5941141B4FD07EED2E16EF1676DC2D46], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied
```

Comment: Use `@Controller` not `@RestController`.

Comment: your logs are clear, read them. You are getting a 404, when accessing /demo/login which redirects you to /error which is protected so it redirects you to login, which redirects you to error which redirects you to login............

Comment: I changed RestController to Controller and created a controller class for /error. Am I doing something wrong in the securityFilterChain?

Comment: `and created a controller class for /error` why did you do this, `/error` is a built in endpoint that spring boot uses, please read the official docs for spring boot, in the very suitable chapter named _error management_

Comment: Thank you. You're right I didn't have to handle error but the controller class with @GetMapping("login").
But it gives me a problem on HSTS:  [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/demo/WEB-INF/pages/login.jsp?continue to session
[nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/demo/login
Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
[nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND

Comment: That is not an HSTS error that is just debug logging. It redirects again. Also don't add additional logging as comments as that is totally unreadable. Add a rule to Spring Security for `/error` to alow all access. That will at least give you information on what is happening. Finally remove the `@RequestMapping` from the top of your class, only leave `@Controller` there. You have now effectifly mapped that controller to `/login.htm/login` instead of your `/login` hence a 404, hence an error, hence a looping redirect.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things wrong with your `LoginFormController`

1. It uses `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`
2. It has a top-level `@RequestMapping` leading to effectively mapping your login page to `/login.htm` and not `/login`.

Instead of defining a controller do the following.

Ditch your `LoginFormController` and add the following class.

```java
@Configuration
public ViewOnlyConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
  }
}
```

That is all you need. This will automatically create a controller which will render the proper page. No need to add a controller yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your support. But do I have to give some kind of permission to the request? because it gives me error: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied

Comment: Well you only allowed `/login` in your security configuration. If you use images or stylesheets etc. in your login page those will be blocked. Also as mentioned before open up `/error` with a `permitAll()`.

Comment: Thank u, now it works when I use .requestMatchers("/error","/css/**","/WEB-INF/pages/*","/js/**","/img/**").permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing `@RequestMapping("/login.htm")` to `@RequestMapping("/login")`

just like below -

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginFormController {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Returning login view");

        Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        return new ModelAndView("login", "model", myModel);
    }
    
}
```

if that doesn't work the try the below code

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginFormController {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());


    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, ModelAndView model) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Returning login view");

        model.setViewName("login");
        return model;
    }
    
}
```